# Sublime SFTP upload folder on save

Tags: ftp, sublimetext2, sftp, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I use Sublime SFTP plugin to work with remote server.

My configuration for some project looks like this:

```
{
    // The tab key will cycle through the settings when first created
    // Visit http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/settings for help

    // sftp, ftp or ftps
    "type": "sftp",

    "save_before_upload": true,
    "upload_on_save": true,
    "sync_down_on_open": false,
    "sync_skip_deletes": false,
    "sync_same_age": true,
    "confirm_downloads": false,
    "confirm_sync": true,
    "confirm_overwrite_newer": false,

    "host": "MY_HOST",
    "user": "MY_USER",
    "password": "MY_PASSWORD",
    "port": "22",

    "remote_path": "/MY_REMOTE_PATH/",
    "ignore_regexes": [
        "\\.sublime-(project|workspace)", "sftp-config(-alt\\d?)?\\.json",
        "sftp-settings\\.json", "/venv/", "\\.svn", "\\.hg", "\\.git",
        "\\.bzr", "_darcs", "CVS", "\\.DS_Store", "Thumbs\\.db", "desktop\\.ini"
    ],
    //"file_permissions": "664",
    //"dir_permissions": "775",

    //"extra_list_connections": 0,

    "connect_timeout": 30,
    //"keepalive": 120,
    //"ftp_passive_mode": true,
    //"ssh_key_file": "~/.ssh/id_rsa",
    //"sftp_flags": ["-F", "/path/to/ssh_config"],

    //"preserve_modification_times": false,
    //"remote_time_offset_in_hours": 0,
    //"remote_encoding": "utf-8",
    //"remote_locale": "C",
}
```

When I save file, SFTP uploads it, but when I create new folder or new file and save again, only edited file is uploaded (not new folders or files) and I have to manually "tell" SFTP to upload them (from side bar Context Menu).

I have `"upload_on_save": true` in my config file. What's wrong?

Is there another configuration or trick to upload new folders and files on save?

Comment: have you emailed support@wbond.net? He's usually pretty good about helping out with issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a folder doesn't "save". If you create a folder and then create a file within that folder and THEN save, it should try to create the folder on the server, or at least ask if you want to create it.

Comment: This is right, the 'upload on save' setting doesn't mean it will upload everything on any save, it only uploads the file that is saved.